# Automatically adjusting size of cells in a gridview in android

Tags: android, xml, android-gridview

Am developing a custom gallery using gridview in android. Now am facing the issue with the columns count ..my gridview xml is,

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:columnWidth="179dp">
</GridView>
```

my grid item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="179dp"
    android:layout_height="131dp"
    android:padding="1dp" >
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
        android:contentDescription="@string/iv_content_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_folder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/tv_folder" 
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

of course it's dynamically maintaining columns according to device width but there is different column spacing in different devices..
how i can overcome this issue.?

Comment: can you upload a picture?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast plese check the uploaded image

Comment: The behavior is kind of expected. you're explicitly setting the height and width to pixel values. when the (number of columns x your width) can't hold any more images, it stretches them to a "auto fit" and moves on to to a new row. You can make use of HorizontalSpacing though to control the spacing between images to a fixed size but then you'll have extra white spaces at the right side. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: @kha is there any method to distribute this uniformly?

Comment: It's not easy unfortunately with the built in grid. The problem is, images vary in size and specially in orientation, so traditional approaches don't quite work since if you simply specify WrapContent, you'll get differing sizes of your image thumbnails which will mess up your grid because of differing width/height. You can however implement a custom solution like this one which should allow you to auto scale your images to fit your grid: http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distribute the size uniformly don't use a fixed size for each grid item.

Set the width to wrap_content and you can also specify the number of columns